# Logout request returns http 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to make a basic configuration for spring-security in version 3.0.7.
When I go to `/logout` URL I get HTTP 404 and the user is still logged. What is more, despite it has `permitAll` access I see that spring scan whether the logged user has ROLE_USER (probably there is something wrong with  `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>` as it takes every request not looking on other rules). What is wrong here?

I don't want to use any JSP files!!!! Just backend here. It can return a blank page after logout.

**application-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/asd" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/users" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" />
        <http-basic/>
    </http>
    
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin1" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    
</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/myServlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Spring in its version 3.0.7 is way beyond its EOL. Is it really necessary to proceed with a nearly 10 year old version?

Comment: @mle it's for my engineering thesis and yes, I need that

Comment: try adding this line `<csrf disabled="true"/>` in your http tag.